# Regular expression to find a pattern and the first occurrence of another text pattern before it

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to extract an event from a log file plus the time it happened. Unfortunately the log file is not very structured, as the 3rd party logger inserts time stamps asynchronously to my logged text. I can identify the event by `ID:00000015fd6c`

An example is :

```
[2017/4/16 2:28:29AM]  (I) Radio mode changed to 
SYSAXRADIO_E_STATE_PAGER_RX_SYNC on 170.9 MHz

[2017/4/16 2:28:37AM]  Tock = 1718 
(I) IDTAG TAG : -90dBm : ID:00000015fd6c
(I) ***************
(I) ID TAG DETECTED 00000015FD6C
(I) ***************
```

Currently the regex I have is:
`(?<=2017)[\s\S]*?ID:00000015fd6c`

I want:

```
[2017/4/16 2:28:37AM]  Tock = 1718 
(I) IDTAG TAG : -90dBm : ID:00000015fd6c
```

but I get:

```
[2017/4/16 2:28:29AM]  (I) Radio mode changed to 
SYSAXRADIO_E_STATE_PAGER_RX_SYNC on 170.9 MHz

[2017/4/16 2:28:37AM]  Tock = 1718 
(I) IDTAG TAG : -90dBm : ID:00000015fd6c
```

The text I want is the all including "ID:00000015fd6c" backwards up to the first time stamp before the matching text.

Help please?

Comment: Is `ID` fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) like this:

```
\[2017\/(?:(?!\[\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d)[\s\S])*?ID:00000015fd6c
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9I5tXQ/2)

**Details**

- `\[2017\/` - a `[2017/` string
- `(?:(?!\[\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d)[\s\S])*?` - any symbol, 0+ occurrences, as few as possible, that does not start a sequence:

  - `\[` - a literal `[`
  - `\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d` - 4 digits, `/`, 1 or 2 digits, `/`, a digit
- `ID:00000015fd6c`  - a `ID:00000015fd6c` string